# How do we migrate Azure app service plan from App service environment v2 to App service environment v3

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-app-service-plans, app-service-environment

I am looking to migrate my App service plan from one app service environment v2 to app service environment v3 using ARM Template but I am getting error as server farms belongs to different hostingplans.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Mir Raonaq from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team! Consider using the [App Service Environment (ASE) v3 migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/migrate)

This feature will allow you to migrate your existing ASE environment to ASE v3. Here is a step-by-step guide on the [migration process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/how-to-migrate?pivots=experience-azp).